# Android Studio XML Layout file exist but I can't find it

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

I wanted to create a `Fragment` in **Android Studio**, so I did the following steps:

1. Right click on package
2. New -> Android (Other) -> Fragment (List)
3. Checked both *include fragment factory methods?* and *switch to grid view on large screens*

The description said *"Creates a new fragment containing a list that can optionally change to grid when on large screens."*

**Here's the funny part:** As I was reading the code to understand how this switching is done, I could **not** find any code that switched `XML` files or anything. The only odd thing that I found is that the `XML` used for the `Adapter` was called `R.layout.fragment_item`, **but there was no XML called like that in my layout folder.**

There were 2 XML called `R.layout.fragment_item_list` and `R.layout.fragment_item_grid`. So I though *"hey, maybe internally the framework auto decide if going for* `_grid` *or* `_list` *and that's why it doesn't mark* `R.layout.fragment_item` *it as non-existent"*

When I was done reading the code, I deleted both `R.layout.fragment_item_list` and `R.layout.fragment_item_grid`from my layout folder and guess what? `R.layout.fragment_item` is **NOT** marked as non-existent, and there is no such file inside my Layout folder.

I already went **Build > Clean** and **Build > Rebuild Project** and it still marks it as existent. Am I missing something here? sounds like there is some basic stuff I haven't taken into account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just found what was going on. Inside `values/refs.xml` there was `<item name="fragment_item" type="layout">@layout/fragment_item_grid</item>` which should be the cause of it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I didn't understand your solution as I couldn't see refs.xml in the values folder.

For anybody out there, this is what worked for me: 
In Android Studio go to **File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...**